# Cumulative sum with opencl

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I tried to implement cumulative sum with opencl as follows:

```
__kernel void cumsum(__global float *a)
{
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    int n = get_global_size(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i <<= 1)
        if (gid & i)
            a[gid] += a[(gid & -i) - 1];
}
```

I called this code using pyopencl:

```
import pyopencl as cl
import pyopencl.array as cl_array
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(50000).astype(np.float32)

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

a_dev = cl_array.to_device(queue, a)

with open("imm/cluster.cl", 'r') as f:
    prg = cl.Program(ctx, f.read()).build()

prg.cumsum(queue, a.shape, None, a_dev.data)
print(np.cumsum(a)[:33], a_dev[:33])
```

However, the first 32 numbers are correct, after which they're wrong (too low).  Is this something to do with the work group sizes?  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When **i** becomes large enough, you will be reading the output of another work-group.  Nothing in the OpenCL execution model guarantees this other work-group will have finished execution.

In general it will not be the case, and you will read a partial sum, getting lower values than expected at the end.

Comment: Thank you. I believe these are called "scanning algorithms"?  Do you by any chance know of a good tutorial?

Comment: Since you are using PyOpenCL, you could probably take a look at [its implementation of such algorithms](http://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/algorithm.html#module-pyopencl.scan).

Comment: @bogdan: Thank you, I did find that page, but it's not the clearest tutorial.  I'm reading the specification pdfs, which are more complete, but not the greatest.

Comment: This answer is correct.  However, the problem I was seeing was happening at element 32 — much smaller than the work group size (400).  Adding a memory barrier caused the problem to happen at element 400 as predicted by Eric.